# Interactively merge files tracked with git and untracked local files

Tags: git, command-line, merge, diff, interactive

I use a couple of software packages (like gitlab) that you install by cloning from their git repo. They typically come with some `config.example` (under version control), which you copy to your own `config` file (not under version control or even ignored in `.gitignore`) and adapt to your needs.

When the upstream package is updated and for example changes the config file options that will obviously only be reflected in `config.example`.

Is there a chain of git commands that i'm missing that can help me compare the changes of `config.example` to the new one in `upstream/HEAD` and maybe even merge them interactively into my local `config` file?

Would be awesome if i could get something like the interactive patch mode in `git add/commit --interactive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git checkout --patch` selects diff hunks, simplest here might be to put your content at the upstream path, do that, and clean up after:

```
cp config  config.example
git checkout -p upstream   config.example
mv config.example  config
git checkout @  config.example
```

that will get you the two-diff hunk selection from `git add --patch`.

Answer (score 2):

- You can use `vim` as a merge tool with `vimdiff`.
- `Emacs` can do this as well with `ediff-mode`.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably approach this in many ways.  I could think of two:  [`git-merge-file`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file) and good old `patch`.  The `git-merge-file` method offers some interactivity, whereas the `patch` method offers none.

## Solution with  `git-merge-file`

Lets say you have an original file `config.example` which you use to create a local unversioned file, `config.local`.  Now when upstream updates `config.example`, you can follow something like the following steps to merge any new changes.

```
$ git fetch
$ git show master:config.example > config.example.base
$ git show origin/master:config.example > config.example.latest
$ git merge-file config.local config.example.base config.example.latest
```

This will update `config.local` with the usual conflict markers, which you will then have to resolve with your favourite merge tool (`ediff` in Emacs is nice, I'm sure there are similar modes for Vim).  For example, the following three files,

**config.example.base**:

```
Original: 
          some config
```

**config.example.latest**:

```
Original: 
          some config

Upstream:
          new upstream config
```

**config.local**:

```
Original: 
          some config

My changes:
          some other config
```

will be merged like this:

```
Original: 
          some config

<<<<<<< config.local
My changes:
          some other config
=======
Upstream:
          new upstream config
>>>>>>> config.example.latest
```

You could probably script this without much effort.  Btw, `git-merge-file` can operate on any 3 files, they need not be version controlled under `git`.  That means one could use it to merge any three files!

## Solution with `patch`:

Assuming the same file names, `config.local` and `config.example`, the following should work.

```
$ git fetch
$ git diff master..origin/master -- config.example | sed -e 's%\(^[-+]\{3\}\) .\+%\1 config.local%g' > /tmp/mypatch
$ patch < /tmp/mypatch
```

Comment: I like this answer for the 3-way-merge, but sadly it's not at all interactive like `git add -p`, meaning i can't really review new config options. It has my upvote nevertheless, as this might be the way to go for others.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full git merge, you can get git to do it with arbitrary content by setting up an index entry as `git read-tree` does and then invoking git's normal merge driver on just that entry. Git refers to the different content versions as "stages"; they are 1: the original, 2: yours, 3: theirs.  The merge compares the changes from 1 to 2 and from 1 to 3 and does its thing.  To set it up, use `git update-index`:

```
orig_example=        # fill in the commit with the config.example you based yours on
new_upstream=        # fill in the name of the upstream branch

( while read; do printf "%s %s %s\t%s\n" $REPLY; done \
| git update-index --index-info ) <<EOD
100644 $(git rev-parse $orig_example:config.example)  1 config
100644 $(git hash-object -w config)                   2 config
100644 $(git rev-parse $new_upstream:config.example)  3 config
EOD
```

and you've staged a merge of custom content for that path.  Now do it:

```
git merge-index git-merge-one-file -- config
```

and it'll either automerge or leave the usual conflict droppings, fix it up as you like and `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch` (or keep) the index entry if you want.

The pathname you put in the index (the "config" in all three entries here), by the way, doesn't have to already exist or have anything to do with anything. You could name it "wip" or "deleteme" or anything you want.  The merge is of the content id'd in the index entry.

I think that's likely to do what you want here.  If you really do want to pick and choose from the upstream changes you can put your own content at config.example and do `git checkout -p upstream -- config.example`, that does the inverse of `git add -p`, then put things back the way they were.

Comment: I mostly like this answer for its last paragraph (the rest seems a bit too much like black magic to me). With the idea from the last paragraph I can just do `cp config config.example ; git checkout -p upstream -- config.example` then interactively decide how to merge the changes and finally run `mv config.example config && git reset config.example && git checkout -- config.example` to set things back. If you split the last paragraph off into a separate answer, i'll accept it for its clarity and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

To diff just `config.example` in your local repo with the corresponding file in `upstream/HEAD` you can run:

```
git diff upstream/HEAD config.example
```

Unfortunately I don't know of a way to make git directly apply the changes to a file that git doesn't track.

Comment: yes, i know how to get the diff, but now interactively applying that to `config` is my actual question :-/

Comment: Have you tried copying your updated config file over config.example, checking that in, using your standard tools for merging from origin, then moving it back to config and resetting to before you committed the change to config.example?  If the files aren't too out of sync you should get at least some help merging in just what changed.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a tool called sdiff](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Interactive-Merging.html#Interactive-Merging) that might do what you want.

Invoke it (in your case) with `sdiff -o config config.example config`

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
git diff <some-args> | perl -pe 's/path\/to\/changes\/file/path\/other/g' > t
patch -p1 < t 
rm t
```