# git merge-file fails with bash process substitution operator that uses git show

Tags: git, bash, fifo

I'm trying to merge changes from a file which is in git into one which isn't under version control ([more context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30828886/1423333)) using a 3-way-merge.

As there is a `git merge-file <local> <base> <other>` which expects 3 files and as I don't fancy creating intermediate files and forgetting to clean them up, i used the bash `<(...)` process substitution operator as i do quite often.

It turns out that this doesn't seem to work as expected as the following example shows on git 2.4.2 and 2.4.3 on two different systems.

### Example:

Let's create a small test for this so we know what we're talking about. We'll create a file `foo.txt` (the one in git with 2 versions at least) and a file `bar.txt` which is not under version control:

```
git init
echo -e 'foo\nbar' > foo.txt
git add foo.txt
git commit -m'init'
echo -e 'foo\nbar\nend' > foo.txt
git commit -a -m'end'
echo -e 'start\nfoo\nbar' > bar.txt
git show HEAD^:foo.txt > foo.txt.base
git show master:foo.txt > foo.txt.end
```

This leaves us with a couple of files that look like this:

#### foo.txt @ HEAD^ & foo.txt.base:

```
foo
bar
```

#### foo.txt @ master & foo.txt.end:

```
foo
bar
end
```

#### bar.txt:

```
start
foo
bar
```

### With intermediate files:

So now let's run `git merge-file -p bar.txt foo.txt.base foo.txt.end`:

```
start
foo
bar
end
```

This is the output i'd like to get with the following method as well.

### With Process substitution:

But if i run: `git merge-file -p bar.txt <(git show HEAD^:foo.txt) <(git show master:foo.txt)`, i get this output:

```
start
foo
bar
```

This is not expected and (sometimes!) `echo $?` prints `1` indicating an error.

What's even weirder is that as i couldn't understand this behavior i decided to re-run the above command (up-arrow) and was even more puzzled when this output appeared:

```
<<<<<<< bar.txt
start
foo
bar
=======
foo
bar
end
>>>>>>> /dev/fd/62
```

As i didn't really expect this fail, much less to be non-deterministic i ran again a couple of times to find this output as well:

```
<<<<<<< bar.txt
start
foo
bar
=======
>>>>>>> /dev/fd/62
```

To narrow down the problem i tried `git merge-file -p bar.txt <(echo -e 'foo\nbar') <(echo -e 'foo\nbar\nend')` which reliably prints the expected merge:

```
start
foo
bar
end
```

### Question

Can someone explain this weird behavior?

I can obviously fix it by not using process substitution, but i'd like to understand why this happens as i'm using process substitution in a lot of bash scripts. Also i'd be interested in workarounds which allow me to still use process substitution.

Also if you think this is a bug i'm interested in which component it originates from: `git show`, `git merge-file` or bash?

Comment: The question was too long for me to read through, but there's one general possibility why process substitutions in Bash fail: process substitution basically gives you a character device, which is not seekable, but the command might expect a seekable file. In Zsh there is `=(` instead of `<(` to solve this problem; don't know a bash builtin equivalent.

Comment: You might as well try to run the same workflow in Zsh, with `<(` replaced by `=(`. If it works, then most likely it's the problem I outlined above.

Comment: well, i'm sorry for the length, but that's why i tried `git merge-file -p bar.txt <(echo -e 'foo\nbar') <(echo -e 'foo\nbar\nend')` in the end... if it was what you describe that should fail as well, no?

Comment: Without reading the context (sorry), I'd say it won't necessarily fail (sometimes they are clear errors, sometimes the result is garbled, sometimes it just happens to work — by "sometimes" I mean some commands with some certain input — not to say the behavior should be indeterministic). Would you please try your workflow in Zsh as I recommended? Thanks. (Just trying to point out a general possibility which you should always consider anyway when process substitution fails.)

Comment: just did, on zsh `git merge-file -p bar.txt =(git show HEAD^:foo.txt) =(git show master:foo.txt)` seems to work reliably while `<(...)` shows the same issues...

Comment: See, then there it goes. `seek` problem. Standard.

Comment: ok, so it seems to be a char dev problem, but why only with `git show` not with `echo`?

Comment: That I don't know. Anyway, I wouldn't rely on that since here `echo` falls into the "happens to work" category, and might as well fail with other inputs.

Comment: @4ae1e1 if you provide your comment as answer i'll accept and close this

Comment: Feel free to write up your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164109) this might be a problem with `<(...)` providing a FIFO like file that doesn't support `seek`. The same behavior is shown in ZSH unless invoked like this:

```
git merge-file -p bar.txt =(git show HEAD^:foo.txt) =(git show master:foo.txt)
```

This means that the problem originates from `git merge-file` expecting files that it can `seek` on, while `<(...)` doesn't provide these.